# Can I Add extension while running automation script in headless mode?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, automation, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to add header using extension for my automation script. However, it is not supported for headless mode. Can we automate script using headless mode?

Code:

```
private static ChromeOptions getChromeOptions() {
        final ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        
        final DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        
        options.addExtensions(new File("./src/main/java/com/extenstions/ModHeaderExtension.crx"));
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        return options;
    }
```

Browser initialization:

```
public static WebDriver startBrowserInitialization() {
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(environment.checkHeadless())){
driver.set(new ChromeDriver(getChromeOptions())}
```

Error screenshot:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/_generated_background_page.html
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/_generated_background_page.html 
Host info: host: 'PC-INDU', ip: '192.16.20.133'
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.5'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --headless, --window-size=1920,1080, --start-maximized], extensions: [Q3IyNAMAAAAYBAAAEqwECqYCMII...]}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --headless, --window-size=1920,1080, --start-maximized], extensions: [Q3IyNAMAAAAYBAAAEqwECqYCMII...]}}}]
```

Can we automate script using headless mode?

Answer (score 0):

as Per chromium devs they wont fix this [Read here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2591&q=headless%20extension%20background&can=1)

you can try changing headless argument in your code to below to use new headless mode [New Headless Mode](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1380881), but problem it does show a running chrome instance you cannot access the instance but it does show but it should load you extension properly

```
options.addArguments("--headless=new");
```